# How to display uploaded images in "Change List" page in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, changelist

I'm trying to display uploaded images in **"Change List" page** in Django Admin:

[image]

This is my code below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    image = models.ImageField()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'image',)
```

So, how can I display uploaded images in **"Change List" page** in Django Admin?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can create a model instance method with another name, allow HTML tags for its output and add this method as a list field. Here is an example:

First add a new method returning the HTML for the image inclusion:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def admin_image(self):
        return '<img src="%s"/>' % self.img
    admin_image.allow_tags = True
```

Then add this method to the list:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    ...
    list_display = ('url', 'title', 'admin_image')
```

Comment: Got a problem. Could you take a look pls

TypeError at /admin/

'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Comment: Actually fixed the previous one, now have this:
'admin_img' is not a callable or an attribute of ....

Comment: submited an "edit" to correct the typo. waiting for peer review

Comment: Any way to give it a custom label /verbose_name ? Use .short_description

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE 2020**

Because this answer is getting a lot of traction recently, I decided to make small edit.
According to django doc it is recommended to use function **format_html**.
As @chem1st suggested, if you need it only for admin, everything can be made in **admin.py** only.

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 20, default = 00.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=change_image_name, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**My admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

from .models import Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'image_tag')

    def image_tag(self,obj):
        return format_html('<img src="{0}" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />'.format(obj.image.url))

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

**UPDATE django 2.0.6**

I was solving this problem in latest **django 2.0.6**. I wanted have an image thumbnail in a list view in the django-admin.

**Picture below is my default admin listview.**

[image: This is my default admin view]

**This is my `models.py:`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 20, default = 00.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=change_image_name, null=True, blank=True)

    def image_tag(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.image.url)
        else:
            return 'No Image Found'
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> Please notice I had to use mark_safe() on the image string, otherwise you
> will get escaped html code instead of a thumbnail in the django-admin

**Finally, this is my `admin.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Product
# Register your models here.
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'image_tag')

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

> Here we have to register the **ProductAdmin class** too, I didn't know that
> and it didn't work.

**This is result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, however I'd move `image_tag` method to `admin.py` if you need it for admin site only.

Comment: @shaan gola - You are welcome, I have made small update of my answer. Have a great day.

Comment: sorry for spam. but i must thank you for this details ;X   works fine in Django 3.2.x

Answer (score 14):

```
def image_tag(self, obj):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % obj.image

image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

and in your admin.py add:

```
   readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can also add the image directly in admin

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        
     def admin_image(self, obj):                       
        return '<img src="%s"/>' % obj.img
     admin_image.allow_tags = True

     list_display = ('name', 'price', 'image', 'admin_image')
```

Comment: Better solution for architecture.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm using Django 1.5)
In addition to following the steps in the accepted answer, I ALSO had to mark the image tag as being "safe"

To do this, wrap the return value with the mark_safe method of django.utils.safestring package.

code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075441/1063031

django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **`image_tag` column** with `image_tag()` then assign it to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):         # Here
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'image', 'image_tag')

    def image_tag(self, obj): # Here
        return format_html(
            f'''<a href="{obj.image.url}" target="_blank">
                  <img 
                    src="{obj.image.url}" alt="{obj.image}" 
                    width="50" height="50"
                    style="object-fit: cover;"
                  />
                </a>''')
```

Then, you can display uploaded images in **"Change List" page** in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307307/django-admin-show-image-from-imagefield/75135077#75135077) explaining how to display an uploaded image in **"Change" page** in Django Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite django admin view for your model. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates for more details.

In a brief you need to create a template: templates/admin/your_app/article/change_form.html
And there add html to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Per @TomRavn comment,
**mark_safe** works for me.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.html

Answer (score 0):

###### models.py

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class Test(models.Model):
    title                   = ...
    photo                   = ...
    
    def image(self):
        return format_html('<img src="%s"/>' % self.photo.url)
```

###### admin.py

```
@admin.register(models.Test)
class testAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =    ('title','image')
```