# Change Django admin list layout

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django application that have a lot of images items that have to be reviewed by content. So, I've made in the admin, when I list the images items, to see the thumbnails of the items instead of the ugly " string (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/django-display-image-in-admin-interface)).

My problem is that the list is displayed on the vertical (1 image per line). Can I change the admin list layout to display more items per line? (the only item in my list is the image, there is no other information like url and title like in the example above)

Comment: Why not write your own admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

customize admin view http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin

Comment: I don't know how I've missed this. The more accurate link would be this one: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 0):

You could to that with some JavaScript, like jQuery's Galleria for example.