# Django admin rename image to [IMG]

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a field in database which is use to save a description with rich textbox, below is the data:

```
<p><img title="1" src="/media/upload/thumbnail.jpg" alt="1" width="60" height="60" />5th Freedom of the Air is:</p>
```

When I list in in the admin list(list_display), it shows me the description with image.

How can I change the  to , so that it wont show image?

I want to display  instead of

Comment: I don't get exactly what you are after (display the description instead of the image? display the image and the description? display the image instead of the image path?), but i assume this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/django-display-image-in-admin-interface/2444076#2444076

Comment: Seriously, I don't have a clue about what you are asking. Can you please rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your text should be probably escaped before saving, see:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape