# Django admn error ImproperlyConfigured that is missing from the form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm getting the following error message (see below) when trying to list my products in the Django admin. However I have defined qr_code as you can see.

**ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/products/product/
'ProductAdmin.fieldsets[4][1]['fields']' refers to field 'qr_code' that is missing from the form.**

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    qr_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    qr_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="public/uploads/",
        height_field="qr_image_height",
        width_field="qr_image_width",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False
    )
    qr_image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    qr_image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def qr_code(self):
        return '' % self.qr_url
    qr_code.allow_tags = True
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['title']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'description', 'active')
        }),
        ('QR Code', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('qr_url', 'qr_code')
        }),

    )

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qr_code` cannot be referenced as a method on a model in a form. It has to be defined as a model field or form field if you intend to use it in a form within a model admin.

Comment: any examples of this I can look at?

Comment: Not to be rude, but, maybe the Django documentation? What are you trying to accomplish? Your method for `qr_code` doesn't make any sense - it just returns a string - the `qr_url` property.

Comment: I'm just learning and following this example: http://www.acedevs.com/blog/2011/07/25/quick-qr-codes-django/

Comment: No worries. That's a fairly complicated example for a beginner. Basically, Django expects that a field on a ModelForm directly correlates to a column in a database table.

Comment: but whats confusing me is that all the examples I see where you try to add an image to the admin seem to just call the method not a direct field . whats the difference between this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/django-display-image-in-admin-interface and what I'm doing? To me it looks like he is calling a model method too. confused :( I'm try to add the image to the admin but calling the method in the same way.

Comment: The difference there is that the method is being used in the `list_display` in that ModelAdmin, not referenced as an input in the change form.

Comment: Good deal. I would highly recommend checking out "Practical Django Projects". Of all the books available, this one helped me out the most when learning Django.

Answer (score 1):

Add qr_code to `readonly_fields` in ProductAdmin.

```
readonly_fields = ('qr_code')
```