# Django Admin : Display pictures from Admin Form

Tags: python, django

Unfortunately I didn't handle Django since several months. I would like to know How I can display Django object from my Admin form to my template.

I'm making a personal website and all forms (add pictures, add extra-info, ...) should be from admin panel.

I have a **model.py** file :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class ImageUpload(models.Model) :

    Nom                 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Nom de l'objet", blank=False)
    Instrument          = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Instrument", blank=False)
    Imageur             = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Imageur", blank=False)
    Monture             = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Monture", blank=False)
    Instrument_Guidage  = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Instrument de Guidage", blank=False)
    Imageur_Guidage     = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Imageur de Guidage", blank=False)
    Reducteur           = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Reducteur/Correcteur de Focale", blank=False)
    Logiciels           = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="Logiciels", blank=False)
    Date                = models.DateField()
    Nombre_Pose         = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nombre de pose total")
    Temps_Pose          = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Temps de pose unitaire")
    Integration         = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Temps de pose total")
    Darks               = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nombre de Darks")
    Flats               = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nombre de Flats")
    Bias                = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nombre de Bias")
    Lunaison            = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Pourcentage de Lune")
    FWHM                = models.FloatField(verbose_name="FWHM moyenne")
    Temperature         = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Température")
    Lieu                = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="Lieu de Photo", blank=False)
    Image_upload        = models.ImageField(upload_to='Media/', verbose_name="Image")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode (self.id, self.Nom, self.Instrument, self.Imageur, self.Monture, self.Instrument_Guidage, self.Imageur_Guidage, self.Reducteur, self.Logiciels, 
        self.Date, self.Nombre_Pose, self.Temps_Pose, self.Integration, self.Darks, self.Flats, self.Bias, self.Lunaison, self.FWHM, self.Temperature, self.Lieu, self.Image_upload)
```

I have my **admin.py** file :

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import ImageUpload

class ImageUploadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) :

    fields = ["Nom", "Instrument", "Imageur", "Monture", "Instrument_Guidage", "Imageur_Guidage", "Reducteur", "Logiciels", 
        "Date", "Nombre_Pose", "Temps_Pose", "Integration", "Darks", "Flats", "Bias", "Lunaison", "FWHM", "Temperature", "Lieu", "Image_upload"]

admin.site.register(ImageUpload,ImageUploadAdmin)
```

And my views.py file :

```
def CielProfond(request) :

    Images = ImageUpload.objects.latest("id")

    return render(request, 'CielProfond.html', {"Images" : Images})
```

Finally, in my template file :

```
{% block content %}
<img src='{{Images.Image_upload}}'/>
{% endblock content %}
```

I don't have any error, but my picture doesn't display and I have a small icon. My path seems to be good too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Display image in admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/django-display-image-in-admin-interface)

Comment: @Lemayzeur To my mind, your answer is not good. In your example, user doesn't use `model.ImageField`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I have to add `.url` like this :

```
<img src='{{Images.Image_upload.url}}'/>
```

In this way, my picture is well-displayed in my HTML template