# How to display an uploaded image in "Change" page in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to display an uploaded image in **"Change" page** in Django Admin but I cannot do it as shown below:

[image]

This is my code below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    image = models.ImageField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

So, how can I display an uploaded image in **"Change" page** in Django Admin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `AdminFileWidget` then assign `CustomAdminFileWidget` to [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.db import models
                            # Here
class CustomAdminFileWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        result = []
        if hasattr(value, "url"):
            result.append(
                f'''<a href="{value.url}" target="_blank">
                      <img 
                        src="{value.url}" alt="{value}" 
                        width="100" height="100"
                        style="object-fit: cover;"
                      />
                    </a>'''
            )
        result.append(super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer))
        return format_html("".join(result))

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {           # Here
        models.ImageField: {"widget": CustomAdminFileWidget}
    }
```

Then, an uploaded image is displayed in **"Change" page** in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/how-to-display-uploaded-images-in-change-list-page-in-django-admin/75140612#75140612) explaining how to display uploaded images in **"Change List" page** in Django Admin.